# Constructor using an object of another class as class parameter

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

In my person.cpp file

The constructor person parameter:

pos(&pos1) is not working any suggestion would help greatly.

I've have tried changing variable to a constant:

Position * pos - > const Position* pos

I have also tried removing the const portion of the constructor

I was wondering if there is any other solutions for this issue

```
#include "person.h"

#include "position.h"

Person::Person(const Position& pos1, char type) : pos(&pos1), type(type)
{

}

char Person::getType() const
{
    return type;
}

Position Person::getPosition() 
{
    return *pos;
}

bool Person::operator==(const Person& other) const
{
    if(other.pos == pos)
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool Person::operator!=(const Person& other) const
{
    if(other.pos != pos)
        return true;
    return false;
}

Person::~Person()
{
    delete this->pos;
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include "position.h"

#ifndef PERSON_H

#define PERSON_H


// The base class of Infecteds and Uninfecteds and is abstract


class Person
{
public:
    /** Person object. the base class for infecteds and uninfecteds
     * @parameter pos. the initial position
     * @parameter type. the type of person
     */


    Person(const Position& pos, char type);
    
    /** Gets the current position of the Person
     * @return position. */

    Position getPosition() ;

    /** Gets the type of the person [L, H, A, O, S]
     * @return the type of the Person
     */
    char getType() const; 

    /** Equality operator
     * @parameter other the other person object
     * @return true if this object has the same position as the other and false otherwise */
    bool operator==(const Person& other) const;

    /** Inequality operator
     * @parameter other the other person object
     * @return false if this object has the same position as the other and true otherwise */
    bool operator!=(const Person& other) const;

    /** Moves the Person from the current position to pos. This is a pure virtual function
     * @parameter move determines the direction to move. The default value is 'A' for auto  */
    virtual void move(char move = 'A') = 0; 

    /** Virtual Destructor */
    virtual ~Person();
    
protected:


    Position* pos;

    char type;

private:
    
};

#endif
```

////////////////////////////

```
    #include <stddef.h>
    
    #ifndef POSITION_H
    
    #define POSITION_H
    
        enter code here
    
    struct Position
    {
        size_t x;
        size_t y;
        
        Position(size_t x1, size_t y1) //:x{x} , y{y} 
        {
            x = x1;
            y = y1;
        }
        Position(Position& other)// :x{other.x}, y{other.y} 
        {
            x = other.x;
            y = other.y;
        }
    };
    
    #endif
```

Comment: It's just `Position pos;`. References need no `&`  or `*`. Note: If the constructor/function expects a `const Position &` then you can pass temporaries: `Person(Position(1,2), 'A');` But if it is not `const` then you need a named Position.

Comment: `Person::~Person(){delete this->pos;}` -- This will fail miserably if `pos` is the address of a variable that was not allocated with `new`.  `Person` should not assume that the pointer was allocated using `new`.   Then this: `Position(Position& other)/` -- don't write unnecessary functions.  The compiler's default copy constructor does this already, efficiently and without error.  You have two `int` member variables in the `Position` class, thus there is no need to step in and write this function (and possibly make a mistake doing so).  The less code you write, the less bugs will occur.

Comment: Regarding "pos(&pos1) is not working", what do you mean by not working -- it gives a compiler error, it doesn't do what you expected, it gives a runtime error.... etc.